# Why do I get Error Code: 1262 when importing a .csv file?

Tags: mysql

I am still very new to MySQL and am having some trouble. I keep getting error code 1262 when trying to import a .csv file to my table and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have tried allocating more space per column as well as checking my .csv in notepad to see if there was a delimiter missing with no avail.

This is my import query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\DLSubsidized.csv"
INTO TABLE studentaid.directloans_subsidized
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 6 LINES (DLSubsidizedId, SchoolCode);
```

The create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE directloans_subsidized (DLSubsidizedId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Recipients VARCHAR(50), NoOfLoans VARCHAR(50), AmountOfLoans DECIMAL(65,2), NoOfDisbursements VARCHAR(50), AmountOfDisbursments DECIMAL(65,2), SchoolCode int);
```

Comment: error code 1262 tells you that a field is to small for your input. it usually comes with a row number. that helps to find ot.

Comment: That's what is stumping me. I have checked the sized and adjusted multiple times, even to unrealistically large fields yet I still receive the error.

Comment: Then split the csv in half and break it further down by diving the rest that can't be imported. importing is very picky what it expects.

Comment: As rudimentary as it might be I was able to populate the table with the .csv data by removing the DLSubsidizedId and SchoolCode columns, Importing the .csv, Then adding the columns back to the populated table.